# Grub drops into rescue shell

Tags: linux, grub2, dual-boot

I have both Linux and Windows installed on the same disk. Recently I decided to switch to a different Linux distribution. Since then Grub fails and drops into the rescue shell. I found out online that I can boot using following commands:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt6)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

After entering the `normal` command, I get to the usual Grub, where I can select which OS to boot. I tried reinstalling Grub but it seems that the actual problem is that I have two different Grub installations.

These are my partitions:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1128448   1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1161216 471042047 469880832 224,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  471042048 479041535   7999488   3,8G Linux swap
/dev/sda6  479041536 976772004 497730469 237,3G Linux filesystem
```

`/dev/sda6` has the `/boot/grub` directory, so Grub is installed there. `/dev/sda2` has following directories: `Boot`, `Microsoft` and `ubuntu`.

Am I right that I have two different Grub installations? And if yes, which should I use? How to uninstall the other one properly?

Comment: You wrongly installed grub. You should stick with grub's official UEFI installation guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I don't know what has been wrong, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an EFI partition I would suggest you to go delete the previous distro's efi application under esp/boot/efi/EFI/distro_previous. Delete the distro_previous folder and then using your new distro reinstall grub2 on /dev/sda. Run the #update grub or #grub2-mkconfig (refer to your distro instructions) and you should be fine.