# bootloader is stuck at "select cd-rom type"

Tags: boot, grub

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a 2006 iMac with 3GB RAM and Core2Duo processor. I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.6 but was informed that I needed to do a fresh install. So I created a bootable CD using a different Linux machine and attempted to boot using the Apple SuperDrive that is built in to the device.

It didn't want to boot and instead I was presented with the grub menu so after doing a bit of research I performed some edits via the grub command line, using the GRUB manual for reference to locate the linux root filesystem and modify it as follows:

grub> set root=(hd2,gpt2)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-210-generic root=/dev/sr0
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-210-generic
grub> boot

When I hit enter after "boot" the screen went blank and nothing at all happened. So I tried to reboot, using the Alt key to bring up the boot loader. It shows:

1.

2.
Select CD_ROM Boot Type :

However at this point the keyboard stops communicating and no inputs are accepted. I have tried the trick of pressing either "1" or "2" and Enter as it is booting, and that succeeds in registering the numeral after "Boot Type" but, again, no action is taken and the keyboard stops being effective.

At this point the CD is stuck in the SuperDrive and I have no way to eject it. I have tried rebooting repeatedly, and even uplugged the computer completely and then plugged it back in, but it won't budge past this point.

What else can I try to get a response from the boot loader?

Comment: Do not know Mac, but does it have 32 bit UEFI, but is 64 bit system? https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

Comment: yes, it does. however, rather than using one of mattgadient's pre-modded iso files, i used one i downloaded from ubuntu. is it fatal to try to run it without the modifications ?

Comment: You may have the 32 bit UEFI boot file,bootia32.efi. Download & add to USB installer to boot it: Detail: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc & https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support You may find instructions to build your own, but you can just download that file.

Comment: yeah, I did that. i have tried to get back to GRUB menu by pressing ESC or ALT or SPACE keys but none of them work

Comment: I was not able to install Ubuntu to my 2006 PC. Server installed & I was able to install lightweight gui. I was able to install Kubuntu, which surpised me as it is more of a mid-weight flavor.  You may need a Light weight flavor:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) Also used new UEFI install of Kubuntu on external SSD with that old BIOS boot laptop. Only had to add BIOS grub stanza to its HDD. External SSD made old laptop functional.

Answer (score 0):

Your "bootloader" needs to be rebuilt with the proper drivers for the file system(s) that host your vmlinuz, initrd, and / (root file system-where all the files live) OR the compressed kernel, vmlinuz is hosed. Personally, my time is valuable and I would probably try the method in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495618/grub-drops-into-rescue-shell) to fix the issue.
Of course, ensure you have a functioning backup as is always a prerequisite.

Source: lin/win/unix/aix/as400 sysadmin/dba chose me and it took 25+yrs before finally breaking into the field I chose. no regerts

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually got the boot loader to respond. I had to press "2" and "Enter" repeatedly while it was booting up. I started early - while the screen was still grey, and had not gone black yet. From what I have read, this means it was booting using EFI and not BIOS.

I think the reason that booting from grub never worked is that in this line -

grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-210-generic root=/dev/sr0

the location I specified for root was incorrect. I was never able to determine what the proper location should be.

Anyway, it booted using the CD that was stuck in the drive. I was then able to install the image that was on it - Ubuntu 20.04.6 - and now everything works as it should.

Thanks to all who offered suggestions.